# Having trouble using parallel arrays with HTML selection boxes

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, selection

Whenever I run this, I want there to be a continued list with the output, but when I select a new item (such as Umbrella or Raincoat), it replaces the existing one. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

```js
function getTotal() {
  let products = ["Umbrella", "Rain coat", "Swimsuit"];
  let prices = [14.95, 119.99, 40.00];

  let totalPrice = parseFloat(0);
  let output = "<ul>";

  let boxes = document.forms.myform.item.options;
  let quantity = document.myform.quantity.value;

  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {            
    if (boxes[i].selected) {
      output += "<li>" + products[i] + " (Quantity " + quantity + ") Cost: " + (prices[i] * quantity).toFixed(2) + "</li>";
    }
  }

  output += "</ul>";

  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;
  document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = totalPrice;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Product 1: An umbrella costs $14.95</li>
  <li>Product 2: A rain coat costs $119.99</li>
  <li>Product 3: A swimsuit costs $40.00</li>
</ul>

<form name="myform" action="javascript:getTotal()">
  <div>
    Select the item:
    <select name="item">
      <option value="umbrella">Umbrella</option>
      <option value="raincoat">Rain coat</option>
      <option value="swimsuit">Swimsuit</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Enter the quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Add this item to the purchase order.">
</form>

<div id="results"></div>
<div id="totalprice"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you are overwriting the "result" contents each time. Append instead. Also don't use parallel arrays when an array of objects will do.

```js
function getTotal() {
  //Array of products
  let products = [{
      "name": "Umbrella",
      "price": 14.95
    },
    {
      "name": "Rain coat",
      "price": 119.99
    }, {
      "name": "Swimsuit",
      "price": 40.00
    }
  ];



  let totalPrice = parseFloat(0);
  let output = "";

  let boxes = document.forms.myform.item.options;
  let quantity = document.myform.quantity.value;
  //Get the selected value of the drop down
  let selected = document.myform.item.value;

  //Loop through the array
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    //Looking for a match
    if (products[i].name === selected) {
      //Use a template literal to create our string   
      output =` <li>${products[i].name} (Quantity ${quantity}) Cost: ${(products[i].price * quantity).toFixed(2)}</li>`;
      break;
    }
  }

  //Append the output to the UL
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += output;
  document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = totalPrice;
  

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Product 1: An umbrella costs $14.95</li>
  <li>Product 2: A rain coat costs $119.99</li>
  <li>Product 3: A swimsuit costs $40.00</li>
</ul>

<form name="myform">
  <div>
    Select the item:
    <select name="item">
      <option value="Umbrella">Umbrella</option>
      <option value="Rain coat">Rain coat</option>
      <option value="Swimsuit">Swimsuit</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    Enter the quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity">
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="Add this item to the purchase order." onClick="getTotal()">
</form>

<!-- NOTE THE UL NOW HAS THE ID -->
<div><ul id="results"></ul></div>
<div id="totalprice"></div>enter code here
```